# Is it possible to edit files in an s3 buckets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 bucket that has many files. I am trying to scan through all of them and then apply a filter function (regex) to remove content that I don't want in each file. All files format is the same so the filtering will be uniform.

Here is the structure of the s3 bucket keys:

```
o_key=7111/year=2020/month=8/day=11/hour=16/minute=46/second=9/ee9.jsonl.gz
o_key=7111/year=2020/month=8/day=11/hour=16/minute=40/second=1/ee99999.jsonl.gz
```

Is there an s3 feature that allows you to modify the files without creating a new file?

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                             verify=False, config=config)
bckt = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

for x in bckt.objects.all():
    #if the content in a key's path file has this in it:
        #remove its content and save the file
```

Pretty straightfoward however I am new to s3 and boto3 so any ideas or suggestions would help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "object update" in s3.
All you need to do is:
Loop over the bucket objects, read the content, manipulate the content and recreate the object using the same object key. I don't see any added value using a third party here.
Boto3 should be enough here.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, but you could use a Github project like this to help you: https://github.com/tsub/s3-edit/blob/master/README.md

This runs from the command line, if you need to keep it within Python you could use the subprocess module to run the above repo in Python, or you could look for a similar project which is built specifically for Python, I could not find one.